# On page load work out which section is in view

Tags: jquery

I have a single long page website with lots of sections. I have some code which allows the user to move up/down sections 1 at a time by pressing up/down arrows which works well, but the current code falls over if the page loads not at the very top of the website - e.g. if it loads with section 5 in view, then the code to move down fails, as it scrolls up to section 2, basically the code is setting the i variable to 0 on load... What I need is some code to review which section is currently in view based on the scroll position and then set variable i to be the correct value... Is this possible?

HTML example is:

```
<section class="panelSection" id="id_intro">
<p>Contents...</p>
</section>

<section class="panelSection" id="id_text">
<p>Contents...</p>
</section>

<section class="panelSection" id="id_pic">
<p>Contents...</p>
</section>
```

jQuery logic is below:

```
/*  scroll next / prev */
$(document).ready(function() {

var sections = $('.panelSection');
//console.log(sections);
var i = null;


function next(){

    if(i == 0){
        $('.prevBtn').css("opacity","1"); 
    }
    if(i < sections.length -1){
        i++;
        if(i == sections.length -1){
             $('.nextBtn').css("opacity","0.5");   
        }
         $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: sections[i].offsetTop
        }, 800);
    }else{
       // alert('end reached');
    }
}
function prev(){
    if(i == sections.length -1){
        $('.nextBtn').css("opacity","1"); 
    }
    if(i > 0){
        i--;
        if(i == 0){
            $('.prevBtn').css("opacity","0.5"); 
        }
         $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: sections[i].offsetTop
        }, 800);
    }    
}
$('html').keydown(function(e){
    if(e.which == '38'){
        prev();
        //console.log(i)  
    }
   if(e.which == '40'){
        next();
        //console.log(i)   
    }
});
$('.nextBtn').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   next();
});

$('.prevBtn').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   prev();
});  

});
/* end of scroll next / prev */
```

Comment: Not sure if you already tried it, but if you have full screen sections you might want to take a look at [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/), which provide callbacks to accomplish what you are asking for, or even a class in the `body`.

Answer (score 0):

I eneded up using this http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport to get the current .panelSection in-viewport and then translated id of the .panelSection to a numberic value and made the i variable become that... works well but is not idea as the logic is based on hard-coded id names...

So code is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var inview = $('.panelSection:in-viewport').attr('id')
     //console.log(inview);

     if (inview == "id_intro") { i = 0; }
     if (inview == "id_text") { i = 1; }
     if (inview == "id_pic") { i = 2; }


     //console.log(i);

});
```